# Bulk method to validate FCM user tokens?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My db tracks every users FCM token generated via my app.  Every time the app starts on a users phone it validates the users FCM token against my db and if its a new token the db gets updated and all the users subscriptions get updated.

However, if the user hasn't used the app in a while (and the token has exprired) or the user has simply removed my app, how can I determine what tokens are still valid?  Is there any bulk method/api that would allow me to send, say, 1000 user tokens at once to see if they are still valid - then cull the bad ones from my DB based on the response.

I know I can check every ID individually to see what topics the token is subscribed to - a bad token responds a specific error message.  But that is quite inefficient and resource intensive to send one call at a time.  Is there any bulk method that can help me do this?

Comment: Hi @rolinger. Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Daniel - no...never found a solution.  And after all these years, one would think Google would have implemented better FCM controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the FCM token by calling the

```
(GET) https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/YOUR_APP_TOKEN_HERE
[Header] => 'Authorization: key=YOUR_KEY'
```

Simple and easy.

If the token is valid then it will return 200 status codes with some more details in JSON format or if it's invalid then the status code will be 400 with error detail in JSON format.

Answer (score -1):

Adding on Saud's answer, you also need to add `'access_token_auth: true'` in the headers:

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server)

```
curl https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/{fcm_token}
   -H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.c.{...}'
   -H 'access_token_auth: true'
```

Where you replace {fcm_token} with your actual fcm token like `c6x0gnh0R3GJo4CC8A5tj6:APA91bFTzq-mNFisp4QxFrtPKywLwmR1LQ8d5rWIIBMUCiZqHuvUVyzSDXvp1lDfJxLMeKFRZIKQ_KgUIet_oZXg_RRaiiGeEGjGEnAqtZRXynj5ZF0n7ETt1ikwU-W79VtfUFPT_vUb` and replace `ya29.c.{...}` with your auth token.